# Decide concerning the technology I should use for developing an Android app based on an eCommerce domain

Tags: android, titanium, native, phonegap-build

I need to develop an application related to C2C communication in which manufacturers can  directly start communicating with retailers for bulk orders and maintain the order in an easy and fast way. Please suggest what framework i can use. For example: Native android developement, PhoneGap, Appcelerator Titanium.

**PhoneGap**: I have read that you cannot provide rich interactive applications and that it's not good in communicating with Android native apis.

**Appcelerator Titanium**: I need to purchase it and it requires a lot of money to develop an application.

**Native development API**: I have to provide a lot of time and it will be hard to communicate with my database and my web application using web services and it will be for the Android apps only

Which should I use for my app?

Comment: Appcelerator costs $39 for an indie seat, a month. However, all Appcelerator code is also published on GitHub, and can be used for free too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say it depends on:

- Your skills...

  - HTML: PhoneGap, Titanium (our Alloy MVC uses XML)
  - JS: Titanium, PhoneGap
  - JAVA: JAVA
- Your plans...

  - One platform: Android
  - Multiple platforms: Titanium, PhoneGap
- Your requirements...

  - Good UX: Titanium, Android

Titanium is open source and free (appcelerator.org) but we do provide paid (starting at $39/month) services, including [Arrow](http://appcelerator.com/arrow), which is great to quickly build mobile web services to connect apps with any remote data source.

Comment: In my opinion the UX of native Android apps is smoother and more stable than the UX of Titanium apps. Especially scrolling gestures and animations in Titanium apps I developed/tested were notably slower/notchier than in native apps.

Comment: Depends on how you implement it, in particular how (much) you listen to events or do single or batch updates/animations.

Answer (score 1):

When you only want to develop an Android app you should use the native API. It offers most features, the better documentation (IMO) and is easier (and therefore cheaper) to maintain. Additionally it should be easy to communicate with databases and/or web APIs.

The only advantage Titanium offers is the multiple platform support. But when you only want to develop for Android use the native APIs.